# Some gmail fonts unreadable under Google Chrome 37 (CentOS 7)

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, font-face, centos7

Here's some example text from gmail under Google Chrome v37.0:

[image]

Here's the same message text from gmail under Opera v12.16:

[image]

MS core fonts are [installed](http://mscorefonts2.sourceforge.net/).

Here is Google Chrome's advanced font settings

[image]

I configured Gmail under the settings section, but that only defines default outbound font behavior and not what is shown from other users.

Is there a way to clean up the font issue under Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be seeing this Chrome bug which sounds similar:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=374818
I recommend you star it (in the top left) to follow any developments and maybe comment if you have info to contribute.

According to the comments there it affect the latest Chrome 37 version in Linux, and this problem indeed appear in gmail.

You can try the workaround suggested there:

> 4. j.lasock...@intrallect.com:
>      For a bit of a tedious workaround, you can use stylebot to apply global stylesheets to chrome 
>      https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha

and

> 8. twelve.e...@gmail.com:
>      Just to expand on #4 above, specifically for Gmail users, if you install stylebot and use the following rule, you'll have at least a workaround for Gmail (assuming you like OpenSans). I'm not sure if this bug is even tracked by the devs anymore, since it's still sitting in "unconfirmed" status.

```
URL: mail.google.com
css:
div {
    font-family: OpenSans;
}
```

Comment: Pulled up `chrome://flags/` Alt-F not finding "DirectWrite", "directwrite", "Direct Write" or any related combination.

Comment: My bad, that option is windows only. i updated my answer to a more likely one.